# Arrays methods implementation

Tags: java

I am looking at methods of class Arrays:

1. `public static int hashCode(double a[])`
2. `public static void parallelSort(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)`
3. `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`

I see 3 different types of how array could be declared as input parameter.
What is the differenece?

Comment: For the first two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java The third one is a var-args array.

Comment: As you are asking this question, I would really suggest you read through [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html) from start to finish - this is a very basic question. Most basic questions will be answered in those tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

> An array's type is written as type[], where type is the data type of the contained elements; the brackets are special symbols indicating that this variable holds an array

and

> You can also place the brackets after the array's name ... `float anArrayOfFloats[];` However, convention discourages this form; the brackets identify the array type and should appear with the type designation.

And in the case of [method parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html):

> You can use a construct called varargs to pass an arbitrary number of values to a method ... To use varargs, you follow the type of the last parameter by an ellipsis (three dots, ...), then a space, and the parameter name. The method can then be called with any number of that parameter, including none.